# Why jenkins archiving an timestamped artifact after an successfully maven build?

Tags: maven, jenkins

i my test environment, i have setup an jenkins server to build maven projects. 
but i find that jenkins will archiving a timestamp copy of output artifact.
because my build will produces an file large than 1GB, this behavior will make disk become full quickly. and i wonder why jenkins do this? how can i disable it?

the log of my build:

```
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] dg-util ........................................... SUCCESS [21.686s]
[INFO] dg-core ........................................... SUCCESS [18.673s]
[INFO] dg-command-api .................................... SUCCESS [5.513s]
[INFO] dg-platform-api ................................... SUCCESS [8.698s]
[INFO] dg-platform-contract .............................. SUCCESS [5.789s]
[INFO] dg-agent .......................................... SUCCESS [8.560s]
[INFO] dg-agent-bootstrap ................................ SUCCESS [7.607s]
[INFO] dg-platform ....................................... SUCCESS [52.749s]
[INFO] dg-jetty .......................................... SUCCESS [9.833s]
[INFO] dg-platform-bootstrap ............................. SUCCESS [52.126s]
[INFO] dg-platform-web-client ............................ SUCCESS [31.033s]
[INFO] dg-platform-vm-client ............................. SUCCESS [2.657s]
[INFO] dg-document ....................................... SUCCESS [4:11.275s]
[INFO] dist-agent-distribution ........................... SUCCESS [1:18.918s]
[INFO] dist-platform-distribution ........................ SUCCESS [2:53.145s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12:40.439s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Aug 15 13:45:12 CST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 231M/708M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-agent/pom.xml to com.actionsky.dg/dg-agent/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-agent-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-agent/target/dg-agent-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-agent/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-agent-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-agent/target/dg-agent-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-agent/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-agent-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-agent/target/dg-agent-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-agent/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-agent-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-agent/target/dg-agent-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-agent/1.0-20140815.054349-6/dg-agent-1.0-20140815.054349-6.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-agent/target/dg-agent-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-agent/1.0-20140815.054349-6/dg-agent-1.0-20140815.054349-6-sources.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-agent/target/dg-agent-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-agent/1.0-20140815.054349-6/dg-agent-1.0-20140815.054349-6-javadoc.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-agent-bootstrap/pom.xml to com.actionsky.dg/dg-agent-bootstrap/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-agent-bootstrap-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-agent-bootstrap/target/dg-agent-bootstrap-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-agent-bootstrap/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-agent-bootstrap-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-agent-bootstrap/target/dg-agent-bootstrap-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-agent-bootstrap/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-agent-bootstrap-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-agent-bootstrap/target/dg-agent-bootstrap-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-agent-bootstrap/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-agent-bootstrap-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-agent-bootstrap/target/dg-agent-bootstrap-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-agent-bootstrap/1.0-20140815.054350-6/dg-agent-bootstrap-1.0-20140815.054350-6.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-agent-bootstrap/target/dg-agent-bootstrap-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-agent-bootstrap/1.0-20140815.054350-6/dg-agent-bootstrap-1.0-20140815.054350-6-sources.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-agent-bootstrap/target/dg-agent-bootstrap-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-agent-bootstrap/1.0-20140815.054350-6/dg-agent-bootstrap-1.0-20140815.054350-6-javadoc.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-jetty/pom.xml to com.actionsky.dg/dg-jetty/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-jetty-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-jetty/target/dg-jetty-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-jetty/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-jetty-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-jetty/target/dg-jetty-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-jetty/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-jetty-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-jetty/target/dg-jetty-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-jetty/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-jetty-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-jetty/target/dg-jetty-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-jetty/1.0-20140815.054354-6/dg-jetty-1.0-20140815.054354-6.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-jetty/target/dg-jetty-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-jetty/1.0-20140815.054354-6/dg-jetty-1.0-20140815.054354-6-sources.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-jetty/target/dg-jetty-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-jetty/1.0-20140815.054354-6/dg-jetty-1.0-20140815.054354-6-javadoc.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-core/pom.xml to com.actionsky.dg/dg-core/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-core/target/dg-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-core/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-core/target/dg-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-core/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-core/target/dg-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-core/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-core/target/dg-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-core/1.0-20140815.054347-6/dg-core-1.0-20140815.054347-6.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-core/target/dg-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-core/1.0-20140815.054347-6/dg-core-1.0-20140815.054347-6-sources.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-core/target/dg-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-core/1.0-20140815.054347-6/dg-core-1.0-20140815.054347-6-javadoc.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform/pom.xml to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-platform-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform/target/dg-platform.war to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-platform-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform/target/dg-platform-sources.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-platform-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform/target/dg-platform-javadoc.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-platform-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform/target/dg-platform.war to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform/1.0-20140815.054350-6/dg-platform-1.0-20140815.054350-6.war
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform/target/dg-platform-sources.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform/1.0-20140815.054350-6/dg-platform-1.0-20140815.054350-6-sources.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform/target/dg-platform-javadoc.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform/1.0-20140815.054350-6/dg-platform-1.0-20140815.054350-6-javadoc.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-web-client/pom.xml to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-web-client/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-platform-web-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-web-client/target/dg-platform-web-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-web-client/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-platform-web-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-web-client/target/dg-platform-web-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-web-client/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-platform-web-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-web-client/target/dg-platform-web-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-web-client/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-platform-web-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-web-client/target/dg-platform-web-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-web-client/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-platform-web-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-web-client/target/dg-platform-web-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-web-client/1.0-20140815.054355-6/dg-platform-web-client-1.0-20140815.054355-6.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-web-client/target/dg-platform-web-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-web-client/1.0-20140815.054355-6/dg-platform-web-client-1.0-20140815.054355-6-sources.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-web-client/target/dg-platform-web-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-web-client/1.0-20140815.054355-6/dg-platform-web-client-1.0-20140815.054355-6-javadoc.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-web-client/target/dg-platform-web-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-web-client/1.0-20140815.054355-6/dg-platform-web-client-1.0-20140815.054355-6-shaded.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dist-dg-agent/pom.xml to com.actionsky.dg/dist-dg-agent/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dist-dg-agent-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dist-dg-agent/target/dist-dg-agent-linux-x64.tar.gz to com.actionsky.dg/dist-dg-agent/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dist-dg-agent-1.0-SNAPSHOT-linux-x64.tar.gz
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dist-dg-agent/target/dist-dg-agent-linux-x86.tar.gz to com.actionsky.dg/dist-dg-agent/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dist-dg-agent-1.0-SNAPSHOT-linux-x86.tar.gz
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dist-dg-agent/target/dist-dg-agent-windows-x86.zip to com.actionsky.dg/dist-dg-agent/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dist-dg-agent-1.0-SNAPSHOT-windows-x86.zip
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dist-dg-agent/target/processed-jar/dg-agent-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dist-dg-agent/1.0-20140815.054357-6/dist-dg-agent-1.0-20140815.054357-6.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dist-dg-agent/target/dist-dg-agent-linux-x64.tar.gz to com.actionsky.dg/dist-dg-agent/1.0-20140815.054357-6/dist-dg-agent-1.0-20140815.054357-6-linux-x64.tar.gz
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dist-dg-agent/target/dist-dg-agent-linux-x86.tar.gz to com.actionsky.dg/dist-dg-agent/1.0-20140815.054357-6/dist-dg-agent-1.0-20140815.054357-6-linux-x86.tar.gz
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dist-dg-agent/target/dist-dg-agent-windows-x86.zip to com.actionsky.dg/dist-dg-agent/1.0-20140815.054357-6/dist-dg-agent-1.0-20140815.054357-6-windows-x86.zip
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-command-api/pom.xml to com.actionsky.dg/dg-command-api/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-command-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-command-api/target/dg-command-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-command-api/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-command-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-command-api/target/dg-command-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-command-api/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-command-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-command-api/target/dg-command-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-command-api/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-command-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-command-api/target/dg-command-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-command-api/1.0-20140815.054348-6/dg-command-api-1.0-20140815.054348-6.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-command-api/target/dg-command-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-command-api/1.0-20140815.054348-6/dg-command-api-1.0-20140815.054348-6-sources.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-command-api/target/dg-command-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-command-api/1.0-20140815.054348-6/dg-command-api-1.0-20140815.054348-6-javadoc.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-contract/pom.xml to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-contract/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-platform-contract-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-contract/target/dg-platform-contract-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-contract/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-platform-contract-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-contract/target/dg-platform-contract-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-contract/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-platform-contract-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-contract/target/dg-platform-contract-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-contract/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-platform-contract-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-contract/target/dg-platform-contract-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-contract/1.0-20140815.054349-6/dg-platform-contract-1.0-20140815.054349-6.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-contract/target/dg-platform-contract-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-contract/1.0-20140815.054349-6/dg-platform-contract-1.0-20140815.054349-6-sources.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-contract/target/dg-platform-contract-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-contract/1.0-20140815.054349-6/dg-platform-contract-1.0-20140815.054349-6-javadoc.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-document/pom.xml to com.actionsky.dg/dg-document/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-document-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-document/target/dg-document-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.zip to com.actionsky.dg/dg-document/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-document-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.zip
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-document/target/dg-document-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.zip to com.actionsky.dg/dg-document/1.0-20140815.054357-1/dg-document-1.0-20140815.054357-1-all.zip
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-vm-client/pom.xml to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-vm-client/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-platform-vm-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-vm-client/target/dg-platform-vm-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-vm-client/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-platform-vm-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-vm-client/target/dg-platform-vm-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-vm-client/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-platform-vm-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-vm-client/target/dg-platform-vm-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-vm-client/1.0-20140815.054357-6/dg-platform-vm-client-1.0-20140815.054357-6.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-vm-client/target/dg-platform-vm-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-vm-client/1.0-20140815.054357-6/dg-platform-vm-client-1.0-20140815.054357-6-sources.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dist-dg-platform/pom.xml to com.actionsky.dg/dist-dg-platform/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dist-dg-platform-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dist-dg-platform/target/processed-jar/dg-jetty-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dist-dg-platform/1.0-20140815.054413-7/dist-dg-platform-1.0-20140815.054413-7.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dist-dg-platform/target/dist-dg-platform-linux-x64.tar.gz to com.actionsky.dg/dist-dg-platform/1.0-20140815.054413-7/dist-dg-platform-1.0-20140815.054413-7-linux-x64.tar.gz
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dist-dg-platform/target/dist-dg-platform-windows-x64.zip to com.actionsky.dg/dist-dg-platform/1.0-20140815.054413-7/dist-dg-platform-1.0-20140815.054413-7-windows-x64.zip
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-api/pom.xml to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-api/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-platform-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-api/target/dg-platform-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-api/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-platform-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-api/target/dg-platform-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-api/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-platform-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-api/target/dg-platform-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-api/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-platform-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-api/target/dg-platform-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-api/1.0-20140815.054348-6/dg-platform-api-1.0-20140815.054348-6.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-api/target/dg-platform-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-api/1.0-20140815.054348-6/dg-platform-api-1.0-20140815.054348-6-sources.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-api/target/dg-platform-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-api/1.0-20140815.054348-6/dg-platform-api-1.0-20140815.054348-6-javadoc.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-util/pom.xml to com.actionsky.dg/dg-util/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-util-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-util/target/dg-util-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-util/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-util-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-util/target/dg-util-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-util/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-util-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-util/target/dg-util-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-util/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-util-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-util/target/dg-util-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-util/1.0-20140815.054345-5/dg-util-1.0-20140815.054345-5.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-util/target/dg-util-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-util/1.0-20140815.054345-5/dg-util-1.0-20140815.054345-5-sources.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-util/target/dg-util-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-util/1.0-20140815.054345-5/dg-util-1.0-20140815.054345-5-javadoc.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-bootstrap/pom.xml to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-bootstrap/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-platform-bootstrap-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-bootstrap/target/dg-platform-bootstrap-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-bootstrap/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-platform-bootstrap-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-bootstrap/target/dg-platform-bootstrap-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-bootstrap/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-platform-bootstrap-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-bootstrap/target/dg-platform-bootstrap-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-bootstrap/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dg-platform-bootstrap-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-bootstrap/target/dg-platform-bootstrap-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-bootstrap/1.0-20140815.054355-6/dg-platform-bootstrap-1.0-20140815.054355-6.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-bootstrap/target/dg-platform-bootstrap-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-bootstrap/1.0-20140815.054355-6/dg-platform-bootstrap-1.0-20140815.054355-6-sources.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /usr/local/jenkins/jobs/dg-integration-snapshot/workspace/dg-platform-bootstrap/target/dg-platform-bootstrap-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar to com.actionsky.dg/dg-platform-bootstrap/1.0-20140815.054355-6/dg-platform-bootstrap-1.0-20140815.054355-6-javadoc.jar
channel stopped
```

Answer (score 3):

You can configure in your build job configuration to turn that off. Assuming based on what you have written it's maven job where you a are under the maven build step. There is a check box `Disable automatic artifact archiving` which you can use to turn off this behaviour. You will find the button `Advanced...` under `Goals and options`.

Comment: yes, this is an solution, but i do need it's archive for other purpose, i just want it make archive without another timestamp copy.

Comment: Just deploy the artifacts into Repository Manager (Nexus, Artifactory, Archiva) and than you have them. In case of SNAPSHOT's you can cleanup the RPM and only left the released artifacts.